# Find $\pi_1(X)$ and $H_1(X)$ using Seifert Van-Kampen

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm doing some last minute studying for a qual (which is tomorrow!) and wanted to know how to do the following question:

> Let $X$ be the space obtained by adjoining two discs to $S^1$, where the first disc $D_1$ is attached via the map $\partial D_1: S^1 \rightarrow S^1, z \mapsto z^6$ and the second disc $D_2$ is attached via $\partial D_2: S^1 \rightarrow S^1, z \mapsto z^4$.  Compute $\pi_1(X)$ and $H_1(X)$.

The hint is to use the "special case of Seifert Van-Kampen for adjoining two-cells."  I know Seifert Van-Kampen, but I don't really understand this special case or how to use it.  I'm really shaky on a lot of basic algebraic topology questions and just hope most of the questions are point-set tomorrow.  Would someone please help me?

**My attempt:**

I tried to use the adjoining a 2-cell: let $p: D_1 \coprod S^1 \coprod D_2 \to X$ be the quotient map, restrict $p$ to $D_1$, it is continuous, and maps the interior of $D_1$ bijectively to $X- A_1$, where $A_1=p(\partial{D_1})\simeq S^1$.

Then by the theorem on Page 439 of Munkres, topology, $i_*: \pi_1(A_1, a) \to \pi_1(X，x)$ induced by the inclusion map is surjective, with kernel the least normal subgroup generated by the image of $k_1*:\pi_1(S^1, p) \to \pi_1(A_1, a)$, where $k_1*$ is the restriction of $p$ on $\partial{D_1}$.

It turns out that $\pi_1(A_1, a) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$, is the image of $k_1*$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$? I think one can also do the same for $D_2$. But then I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly identified the fundamental group of $D_1 \coprod_{\partial D_1} S^1$, and you would need to iterate your application of Van Kampen to determine what happens after you attach another 2-cell.  Using the same result, you would quotient out by the element represented by the image of $(\partial D_2)_*: \pi_1(S_1) \to \pi_1(D_1 \coprod_{\partial D_1} S^1)$.  This image will be the subgroup generated by 4 in $\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}$, so that the quotient will be $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.

To make the calculation conceptually simpler, the special case that is probably being referred to in the question is the fact that for a connected complex, each 1-cell corresponds to a generator for $\pi_1(-)$ and each 2-cell corresponds to a relation for $\pi_1(-)$ via the attaching map from the boundary onto the 1-skeleton.  I don't have a copy of Munkres on hand right now, but this is Proposition 1.26 in Hatcher.

In this case we have that $\pi_1(X) $ has one generator given by the starting $S^1$, and the attached discs yield the group presentation $\langle x \mid x^4 = x^6 = 1\rangle$, which gives a presentation for $\mathbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.